# Open Graph user generated photos preview with JS-SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I would like to find a way to provide the user a preview of the open graph story he/she is going to publish. The story contains an image the user has taken. (user_generated=true)

Currently I use the FB.api call to publish the story to the user's timeline. But FB.api does not open a window (or iframe) which displays the preview. Here is an example of my current FB.api call:

```
me/namespace:action?event=http://example.com&image:url=http://www.example.com/image/picture1.png&image:user_generated=true&fb:explicitly_shared=true&access_token=xxx
```

This works just fine, but as I mentioned before it does not show a preview.

The best option would be if there is a thing like FB.ui that allows to show the preview.

**EDIT:**
I've already tried the following:

```
    FB.ui({
  method: 'share_open_graph',
  action_type: 'og.likes',
  action_properties: JSON.stringify({
      object:'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
  })
}, function(response){});
```

unfortunately I haven't found a way so that only the image is displayed in the post (post displays the og:image [not the user_generated one] with the description, title ..). But I only want that the user_generated image is displayed - like sharing a normal image with the story. I haven't found any parameters that make that possible.

Comment: Try the Share dialog, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog (not sure if it shows a preview for OG stories as well, but I would assume that it should.)

Comment: I tried those things and edited my question. Any further ideas? ty

Comment: Create an individual object for the photo that the user wants to share with the story.

Comment: i have an individual object:

Comment: Do you mean an object that contains a different 'og:image'? If so there is the problem that I have to specify 'og:title' too. But I only want that the image is displayed.

Comment: An Open Graph Story consists of an action, and an object. If you only have one object, then the story you'll be telling will also be the same for all users.